# DotNetOpenAuth SSO sample behavior

Tags: openid, single-sign-on, dotnetopenauth

On the OpenIdWebRingSso samples (PR (provider) and RP (relying party) - 3.5.0.10357) if I Logout on the PR it doesn't log me out on the RP (on the next page request), and a logout on the RP does not trigger a logout on the PR.

Also, the PR always redirects to login (asking for Username and Password) when user is not authenticated. What I need when browsing a page on the RP that does not require authentication is a request just to check if the user is authenticated. If so, log the user on the RP (that part is fine) but if not, just return a response that the user is not authenticated, without asking to log in (unless I do click on the logIn button or try a access a [Authorize] page). UPDATE: Got that part resolved with "request.Mode = 0;"

So what I need on the RP is to check on every page request weather it is authenticated or not against the PR and only ask for password when necessary. So the questions are:

1) Can I find this code on the samples or other reference?

2) If not, what's the best place to put it on a MVC3 app: 
- httpModule?
- on a base controler and override void Initialize?
- OnActionExecuting (ActionFilterAttribute)?
- somewhere else?

3) Is this approach correct for SSO (I have 5 different sites/domains for one company)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all sites belongs to the same company and share access to a userRepository (database) i decided on a different approach, much simpler and avoids too many redirects:

- Trusted site (relying party (RP) in white list) make request (redirect) to main site (provider) with a return url.
- Main site make sure request (returnURL) is from white list of domains
- Log user (if not logged, displaying login form), mark user as logged in database and add temporary token to user database.
- Main site return (redirect) to RP with token.
- RP look into database using token, logs user and deletes token.

SSOff also easy: just check on every request into user database into bool record (userLogged). NO REDIRECTS. On logout simply change record (userLogged) to false and every site will know.

To avoid the RP always checking the provider if the user has logged (redirecting) and get penalized on SERPs, I add a querystring (?checklog=yes) dynamically to the whitelist sites links urls only after/if the user logsIn. So if I go from site A to site B after logged it will go to siteB.com?checklog=yes which will prompt site be to do a redirect with provider to get and log user...and google will never see a redirect.